# How to loop through cell in table column and check if Regex pattern has match?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

i am trying to write Office Script to loop through table column range and check if Regex PAttern has match. If yes just mark red color:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Workstreams");
    let usedColumn = worksheet.getTables()[0].getColumn("Last Update Time");
    let regexPattern = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(23) ([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ([AaPp][Mm])$"

}
```

how to

1. loop through column?
2. mark cell with red

Thank you for help,
Michal

EDIT 02.02.2023:
Code to try to get value from cell:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Workstreams");
  let usedColumn = worksheet.getTables()[0].getColumn("Last Update Time");
  let dataRange = usedColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
  //const values = dataRange.getValues();
  let regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(23) ([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ([AaPp][Mm])$/;

  for (let i = 0; i < dataRange.getValues().length; i++) {
    let cRow: number = i;
    let rowCell: ExcelScript.Range = dataRange.getCell(cRow, 0);
    let rowValue: string = rowCell.getValue() as string;
    console.log(rowValue);
  } 

}
```

and output is like:
44641.25
44713.21875
44587.1361111111
test

for these values in column:
3/21/22 6:00 AM
6/1/22 5:15 AM
1/26/22 3:16 AM
test

so the issue is that JS is converting string to number somehow...
Best,
Michal

Comment: You can try changing `getValue()` to `.getText()`. That should fix the formatting issue.

Comment: Great thanks worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is at the intersection of javascript and Office Scripts api. You can test if a value matches a regex using string's .match function, for example:

```
let x = "hello".match(/^he.*/);
```

Within x you can get some details (eg: what part of the input matched), but if you just care that you got A match, you can test the return for null

```
if ("hello".match(/^he$/) === null) { 
   ... no match found ... 
} else {
   ... match found ... 
}
```

You can get the values from your table's column by grabbing the range with data, then the values, like so:

```
const dataRange = usedColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
const values = dataRange.getValues();
```

values will be a 2D array of type number | string | boolean. This is a quirk of getRange functions returning 2D areas. Since your column is vertical, the data in it will look like [[row1Data], [row2Data], ... ]

Now you can run a forEach over the values and test the regex. Where the regex fails, you can apply your formatting:

```
values.forEach((rowValues, index) =>  {
   if ((rowValues[0] as string).match(yourRegex) === null) {
      // apply the formatting
      dataRange.getCell(index, 0).getFormat().getFill().setColor('#FF0000');
   }
}
```

Comment: But the only issue that column is formatted as Time and this read format as number:
44641.25 from Time cell: "3/21/22 6:00 AM" so only thing is to convert it and keep as displayed value.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Z8H2fN6 like here this is format which is not answering for Regex

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Workstreams");
      let usedColumn = worksheet.getTables()[0].getColumn("Last Update Time");
      let rowCount = usedColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount();
      let colVals = usedColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues() as string[][];
      let regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(23) ([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ([AaPp][Mm])$/;
    
      for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
          if (regex.test(colVals[i][0])) {
            usedColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getCell(i, 0).getFormat().getFill().setColor("red");
          }
      } 
    }
```

This code iterates through the values in the table column. It also created a regular expression object from the pattern. Using the RE object, it tests the values from the column it's iterating through. If there's a match, it sets the cell color for that value to red.

Comment: I updated topic where i explained that still have issue with code.